# Three possessives of the same idea. Acceptable?

Tags: possessives

> 1. I have a ten-year-experience in teaching
> 2. I have ten years' experience in teaching
> 3. I have ten years of experience in teaching

Are all correct? What's the difference?

Comment: (2) is the most idiomatic; (1)  sounds odd - as though you mean that for ten years you knew what it was like to be a teacher (definition 3 [here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/experience_1) rather than definition 1.)

Comment: What about sentence 3?

Comment: [Sighs.] I didn't think I needed to spell it out that (3) is OK but less idiomatic than (2).

Comment: Asking if something is correct or not is off-topic for the site as it is considered proof-reading and not a question about learning English.